# there must be a design pattern, but which one?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have kind of a three dimensional problem.
lets say you have a class Item and a class Slot implementing the same interface. (I only take two classes, but the problem must scale for a large number of classes). Same goes for Land and Water, implementing the same interface (like landscape, this is not important)

Car and Boat inherits from Item and are very close to each other.
Same for Parking_slot and Harbor_slot, inheriting from Slot. Here you have two dimensions, and i can smell a bridge pattern, but not entirely.

```
class Data:

    @abstract_method
    def do_this():
        pass

    @abstract_method
    def do_that():
        pass


class Item(Data):

    @abstract_method
    def do_this():
        pass

    @abstract_method
    def do_that():
        pass


class Slot(Data):

    @abstract_method
    def do_this():
        pass

    @abstract_method
    def do_that():
        pass


class Car(Item):

    def do_this():
        # actually_do_something

    def do_that():
        # actually_do_something


class Boat(Item):

    def do_this():
        # actually_do_something
        # close to Car

    def do_that():
        # actually_do_something
        # close to Car


class Parking_slot(Slot):

    def do_this():
        # actually_do_something

    def do_that():
        # actually_do_something


class Harbor_slot(Slot):

    def do_this():
        # actually_do_something
        # close to Parking_slot

    def do_that():
        # actually_do_something
        # close to Parking_slot
```

thing is, that has to scale with numbers of Landscapes.

As for the 3d dimension, I would like to have a state machine implemented with that, so i could have different behaviors of do_that and do_this in each state. For example, those states can be how the data is stored, and we will have a boat_csv, car_bdd, Parking_slot_cloud etc collection of classes.

I don't want to have under each Item/Slot an inheritance tree with each Landscape and under each of this tree leaf an inheritance tree for each data state.

I have read all patterns described in the design patterns bible (http://www.uml.org.cn/c++/pdf/DesignPatterns.pdf) and felt like none of them was a match. Do you know any pattern applying to my situation ?

**EDIT** for @Milosz Krajewski:
**Why I don't use the bridge pattern**
I think the bridge pattern can't be applied, since the operation i want to perform on my objects depends of both the Item/Slot and the Landscape dimensions. So i can't isolate the Item/Slot dimension related operations and perform them on one side of the bridge and isolate the Landscape dimension related operations and perform them on the other sid of the bridge

Comment: What is the relation between `foo_A` and `bar_A`? What prevents you from using multiple inheritance and just... doing that (aka why do you need a design pattern to do something?)

Comment: There is no relation in term of code. But if I add a foo_C I will also add a bar_C. Besides that, no code is shared.

Comment: I don't 'need' a design pattern, what i need is to have a scalable architecture.

Comment: @RemiDelassus Can you tell us what you are trying to archive? I mean surely you want to use it somehow and not just programm an abstract framework?

Comment: @syntonym In my usecase, foo and bar would be some classes of an ORM, lets name them Item and Slot (it's not my real usecase though). So A and B would be kinds of Items and kinds of slots. For example, A is land and B is water, so Item_A is a car, Slot_A is a parking spot, and Item_B is a boat and Slot_B a 'port spot'. My different states in the state machine are how data about each is stored, CSV, database and so on.

Comment: I have updated the example so it matches my last comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem. Don't take it too personally (you probably will anyway) but you description is quite unclear. I will describe what I think your problem is (or is-similar-to). If I got it right keep reading, if not, just ignore it.

Problem: we have class hierarchy, let's say: Control <- Button <- Checkbox. Unfortunately we have also another dimension: WinForms and GTK (irrelevant, but they both inherit for some Abstract). So we end up multiplying classes: WinFormsControl, GTKControl, WinFormsButton, GTKButton and WinFormsCheckbox and GTKCheckbox.

Adding new Control/Widget will require writing two classes, let's say, adding RadioButton will require WinFormsRadioButton and GTKRadioButton.
Adding new "toolkit", let's say Qt, will require writing three new controls: QtControl, QtButton, QtCheckbox (and, of course, QtRadioButton). Add third dimension and start crying...

The answer is "Bridge". You create one class hierarchy Control, Button, Checkbox. You put all things which are "toolkit" dependant to ToolkitServices, let's say WinFormServices and GTKServices (and QtServices). Control takes ToolkitService as parameter.

You end up with one hierarchy on the left (Control <- Button <- Checkbox) and second one on the right (WinForms, GTK). The left side "uses" the right side (composition) but adding new toolkit, let's say Qt, is about adding one new class: QtServices, that's all.

Is it the scenario you were trying to describe?

Comment: 1) How do you think I could improve my problem description ?  
2) Like I said in my question, the smell of a bridge pattern is quite present indeed. You actually have understood the problem, but there is a problem in applying this pattern: the operations I want to apply on my objects are not dependant to one of the dimension, but they need to know both of the dimensions to be performed. In this case I can't seperate them like in a bridge pattern.

Comment: I think your description is too abstract. Maybe there are commonalities to be discovered between A and B or Foo and Bar but hiding them behind such names makes it impossible to find (for us). In some sense asking about "what design pattern?" you are asking us to find them and, at the same time, you are obfuscating them.